# WSO2 common registry space and multitenancy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have installed WSO2 Identity server and WSO2 API manager according to documentation of Products Clustering & Deployment Guide "Configuring the Pre-Packaged Identity Server 5.1.0 with API Manager 1.10.0". 
According to this configuration WSO2 IS and WSO2 AM use common registry data-source (for governance and configuration).

Later in WSO2 IS I have added additional tenant - for example vu.lt.

And now when I login to WSO2 IS and WSO2 AM management console as super-tenant admin, all works OK.

When I login to WSO2 IS management console as admin of vu.lt tenant - all is OK.

But  when I login to WSO2 AM as admin of vu.lt tenant I get a little strange view: the header of page is from Identity Manager, but content is from API manager.

After some tests I found out that css file (main.css) is loaded from governance part of registry .../governance/repository/theme/admin/main.css. It means that main.css is loaded from data-source. The same css is loaded when I login from WSO2 IS. The same happen if install one more server (for example BPS) and configure it to use common registry space.

Maybe this situation is not very bad, but I don't know which consequences can I get later.

So, the question is: could I have common registry space in multi-tenancy environment or I have configured something wrong.

Finally I would like to install WSO2 IS, BPS, AM and DAS with LDAP user store and to use this system for Identity Management purposes in our university. I'm not sure which configuration of registry space should I choose: common governance and different configuration, or maybe common configuration too, like in "Configuring the Pre-Packaged Identity Server 5.1.0 with API Manager 1.10.0"?

Comment: Did you try with another browser or a private window? Regarding your question about how to share the registry, you can find more information from http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances/ . The idea is usually you have to share the "config" registry among the same product and governance registry among all the products.

Comment: I tried with different browsers, after full cache and other data clearing, with private windows. Nothing helped me. Main.css is loaded from the same place (registry DB, path /_system/governance/repository/theme/admin) for IS and AM servers.

Comment: Regarding registry space sharing, yes, I have red this document. I agree, that common governance for all products and common configuration for the same products is the best case. But why is proposed a common full (governance and configuration) registry space in documentation about clustering  in chapter "Configuring the Pre-Packaged Identity Server 5.1.0 with API Manager 1.10.0"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the host names?.. Refer to jira [1].

[1]. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-6686

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I will try it. But I'm not sure that this will help me. Main.css is loaded from the same place (registry DB, path  /_system/governance/repository/theme/admin) for IS and AM servers. I think, if I configure each server with its own registry space all will be OK(?) . But I want to have common registry space.